# Omit file name when importing?

Tags: python

Is there any way I could omit the file name when importing a class in Python that doesn't require importing everything in `__init__.py`?

Basically what I have now is the project structure that looks like this:

```
project
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── module1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── SomeClass.py
    │   └── SomeOtherClass.py
    └── module2
        ├── __init__.py
        └── YetAnotherClass.py
```

In the file `SomeClass.py` I have a class named `SomeClass` and so on.
I'd like to be able to import these classes with an import statement like this:

```
from project.module1 import SomeClass
from project.module1 import SomeOtherClass
```

Currently I'm doing this by these imports in `module1/__init__.py` file:

```
from SomeClass import *
from SomeOtherClass import *
```

The thing is that `SomeOtherClass` imports a rather big framework that starts some background services upon import, so I'd like to avoid importing it if the only thing I need from the project is `SomeClass`. Also, since many other projects depend on this one I'd rather not change the import statements needed to access the classes.

I looked for some solution, but didn't really found anything useful.
Is there any clean way to do this without major refactoring?

Comment: I'd say your problem is that SomeOtherClass "starts some background services upon import". You should make that explicit.

Comment: Actually, having background services started on a module import is very bad design - I think you understand why. As far as I'm concerned I'd start with fixing this issue, even if it means breaking client code that currently relies on this (insane) behaviour. Once this is corrected, well, most of your problem is solved.

Comment: And while we're at it: while using package's `__init__` as a facade to submodules is totally idiomatic, it's better to either use explicit imports in the `__init__`, ie `from SomeClass import SomeClass` (best) or at least to restrict what's imported via a wildcard import by defining the `__all__` attribute in the module (less explicit but still better). As a general rule: do not use wildcard imports at all in production code. Also, module names should be "all_lower", and Python neither requires nor even encourage the java-ish "one class per file" scheme.

Comment: Yes, I understand that's a very bad design, but I'm not in control of the framework's code, and most of client code that uses classes from this project also use the framework, so the services are started either way. This is problematic only in case of non-framework client trying to import non-framework class from the project. Also, it's not exactly one class per file, but the classes are distributed among files based on their purpose and this often results in one class per file design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no, you can't.

Upon initial import (the first time a module is imported in a given process), **all** the code at the module's top-level is executed (`import`, `def` and `class` ARE executable statements, and must be executed for the imports to happen and function and class objects to be created).

Given the situation you describe, your options are:

1/ importing `SomeClass` from it's submodule instead of importing it from the package, ie replace `from module1 import SomeClass` with `from module1.SomeClass import SomeClass`. This is the simplest workaround but it's rather brittle, to say the least.

2/ remove the `from SomeOtherClass import *` from your `__init__` and force client code to explicitely import the `SomeOtherClass` submodule. This will breaks client code compatibility but it's at least more explicit.

3/ fix the `SomeOtherClass` module so that it does NOT launch any service behind the hood. **This is actually the only sane solution** - importing a module shouldn't have such side-effects as launching any process or whatever. This will also break client code relying on this anti-pattern and that will now have to explicitely launch those services, whatever they are, but this doesn't require much more effort than solution #2 and at least it will definitively fix the root issue.

Note that there *might* (or not...) be some other workaround, but it's impossible to tell without knowing exactly what happens in your `SomeOtherClass` module, what exactly is this "big framework that starts some background services upon import", and whether this "big framework" already provides some more sensible options to handle how and when those "services" are started.

EDIT:

> The thing about the SomeOtherClass is that it doesn't start any services on it's own, it just uses a framework that does, and the code of that framework is outside my control

I understood that it was not `SomeOtherClass` that started the service(s) but one of it's dependencies. My answer was mostly trying to list the possible technical solutions, at least as much as possible without knowing more - possibly much more than I actually want to know xD - about this framework.

Now as I mentionned, even if you don't have the hands on the framework, it might still (or not) provide a way to avoid implicitely launching those services, but no one can tell without knowing what this framework is.

Also, depending on *exactly* how SomeOtherClass "depends" on this framework, there still might be ways to at least defer the problematic part until some method actually needs it (proxy pattern comes to mind, or at worst a monkeypatch) - but here again it's impossible to tell without having the real code at hand and spending some time inspecting it.

And, finally, even if you don't have the hands on the framework, you might still discuss the issue with the framework's maintainers. Might be a lost cause (if it's a proprietary thing with stubborn / unconcered maintainers or so totally broken that they just can't fix it without rewriting everything) but it's still worth trying as it's technically the best solution.

Comment: Thanks very much! I thought so, but it's always better to ask before requesting changes in tons of client code. The thing about the `SomeOtherClass` is that it doesn't start any services on it's own, it just uses a framework that does, and the code of that framework is outside my control.

Comment: @daneos cf my edited answer. As I say, there might __or not__ be some possible workaround, but it's impossible to tell without knowing _much_ more about the real code.

Comment: Sure, many thanks for your answer! I'll definitely discuss how things are done with the framework maintainers, but even if they fix it, it'll take some time for our code to update to the newest version. I was looking for something more drop-in, but you are right that probably any solution that doesn't deal with the root cause will just make things worse. I guess it's time to start sending out deprecation notices and requesting changes in client code :)

Comment: Perhaps you can wrap functions which depend upon the service, and start the service if it doesn’t exist. For new clients you can provide an initialisation function so the overhead comes at a predictable time.

Comment: @PeterWood that's more or less what I had in mind when I mentionned proxies and / or monkeypatching, but it's really impossible to know if it's even possible (at least at a worthwhile cost) without seeing the actual source code. As a last resort you can do very advanced metaprogramming things with AST, but it's far from simple or straightforward, and can quickly become a major PITA to maintain.